# How do I make a youtube embedded video responsive

Tags: youtube, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap 2.3 and I have embedded some youtube videos. But when I check the responsiveness of the site, the video doesn't seem to get resized accordingly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good article about reponsive video, checkout:

http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/

more variants here:

http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php